# Raise PropertyChangeNotification on Property in different class (different ViewModel)

Tags: c#, mvvm, properties, inotifypropertychanged

**Motivation:**
I'd like to have a 'File->Save As' `MenuItem` that behaves just like in Visual Studio. When there is nothing opened it says "Save Selected Items as..."
and when a particular file (e.g. `SomeFile.cs`) is opened in a tab, the `MenuItem` reads "Save `SomeFile.cs` as...".

---

**My App architecture (`MVVM`, using `MVVM Light`):**

*MainWindow.xaml:*

```
<MenuItem Header="{Binding SelectedProjectName}" HeaderStringFormat="Save {0} As..." />
```

*MainWindowViewModel:*

I hold a collection of opened tabs (opened files)

```
private ObservableCollection<BaseProjectViewModel> _projects;
```

I have a property returning a currently selected tab

```
public BaseProjectViewModel SelectedProject
{
    get
    {
        return _selectedProject;
    }
    set
    {
        if (_selectedProject == value)
        {
            return;
        }
        _selectedProject = value;
        RaisePropertyChanged("SelectedProject");
        RaisePropertyChanged("SelectedProjectName");
    }
}
```

I created a property returning the name of the file in the currently selected tab

```
public string SelectedProjectName
{
    get
    {
        if (SelectedProject == null)
        {
            return "Selected Item";
        }
        return SelectedProject.SafeFileName;
    }
}
```

`BaseProjectViewModel` serves as a base class for various file types. Each file type has its own class derived from `BaseProjectViewModel`. It has properties like for example
`PaneHeader` that returns a string to be displayed in pane header,
`SafeFileName` that returns just the file name of a path etc...

**Question:**
When I change the name of the file (thus changing properties of the `BaseProjectViewModel`) how do I trigger `RaisePropertyChanged` of the `SelectedProjectName` in `MainWindowViewModel`?
What is the cleanest way to do that?

*My thoughts*
I thought of two possible ways to do that, but i don't know if any of them is the correct way to do it:

1. (In short) Listening to `CollectionChanged` on `_projects`. When there is add/remove -> subscribe/ubsubscribe an event handler that would 
   look if the PropertyName is the one we are looking for and if yes subsequently call `RaisePropertyChanged("SelectedProjectName")`?
2. Use something like `MVVM Light Messaging`.

**Question 2:** If you don't suggest any other way and in fact you'd suggest one of these two - could you please elaborate on advantages and disadvantages?

---

**EDIT**

I created a very simple project to demonstrate the issue - [LINK](http://uloz.to/xcrxTrKw/exampleforerno-zip).
When you run the project:

- 'New' adds a new TabItem. When text is edited, the TabHeader is decorated with an asterisk.
- 'Save {0}' menu item "saves" the selected TabItem (simulated by removing the asterisk). I didn't want to complicate the example and introduce a SaveFileDialog and such.
- 'Save As {0}' menu item simulates Save as in such a way that it adds 'X' character to the end od Tab header string.

When no TabItem is selected, the {0} resolves to "Selected Item".

When you have one tab selected, you click SaveAs() and open the menu, you'll notice that change has not been raised on SelectedProjectName property. When you click another tab and then select the first one back, the change is propagated.

**Edit for Erno**: What I fail to understand is this: Let's suppose I have a special menu for each document type. Let's suppose I have one particular tab selected (with it's own menu enabled/visible, the other collapsed). How is it going to help me propagate the PropertyChanged of PaneHeader property in BaseProjectViewMode to SelectedProjectName in MainWindowViewModel? If you have time could you please demonstrate it on the example? I also would like to ask you what would be an alternate way if I wanted/neede to do the wiring? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

From your options I dislike #1 because it might introduce a lot of wiring that is hard to track and maintain.

Option #2 might be OK but could end up in the same wiring mess as #1 but because of the messaging it will be less visible.

I'd consider a different approach:

- put a menu in the MainWindow that is responsible for handling commands when no files are open or selected.
- when a document is opened in a view and has the focus: **replace** the current menu with the document specific menu. (like MDI applications work in WinForms)

This way you can customize the Menu per document (type) and it does not require the event dependencies.

Comment: I just tried your advice and it doesn't solve the problem that I am having: <MenuItem Header="{Binding SelectedProjectName}" HeaderStringFormat="Save {0} as..."  Visibility="{Binding SelectedProject, Converter={StaticResource ObjectVisibilityCollapsedConverter}}" Command="{Binding SaveAsProjectCommand}" />
<MenuItem Header="Selected Item" HeaderStringFormat="Save {0} as..." Visibility="{Binding SelectedProject, Converter={StaticResource ObjectVisibilityCollapsedConverterInverted}}" />. Changing property on BasePRojectViewModel does not propagate to MainWindowViewModel.

Comment: I am sorry but I can't make any sense of your comment. I can't see how you are replacing the menu let alone how this error is caused.

Comment: I didn't want to add specific 'edit' section and the comment space is limited - I apologize. I believe the approach you suggest cannot propagate a change of A.PropertyA to B.PropertyB. When I have two MenuItems (or Menus) and I collapse one/enable other it doesn't solve the problem that when I change the SafeFileName property (e.g. SaveAs the document) the SelectedProjectName property does't update. I might have misunderstood your approach - in that case could you please explain it in greater detail (perhaps pseudocode). If this doesn't make sense please let me know, I will add edit section.

Comment: My suggestion is to have a MainWindow including a default menu and for each type of document a UserControl including a Menu. Bind the Visibility of the Mainwindow's Menu to the fact whether or not a document is open/active/selected. When opening a document simply load the UserControl that includes the correct sub menu. Do not try to wire up properties and events unless really needed. You could consider a single (solution/project) ViewModel that contains a collection of document Viewmodels.

Comment: Please see EDIT and Edit for Erno. I also sent you the project via email as I had problems finding a reliable online hosting site.